# How to set PcManFm as the default file manager?

Tags: filemanager, pcmanfm

I think Nautilus is so slow, and I'd like to move to PCmanFM, but didn't find any good tips how to do this in Ubuntu 12.10.

I have PCmanFM installed already, and I even changed:

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=pcmanfm %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.2.1
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus
```

Still slow Nautilus is default one.

Answer (score 14):

After struggling with this Nautilus' slowness for a while, I decided to change my default as well. All of the "proper" solutions I tried doing didn't work very well. For instance, choosing the default in `exo-preferred-applications` didn't update the dash (or much else for that matter), changing `.desktop` files only worked sometimes (Dropbox still used nautilus), etc.

The simple solution that works for me in *all* cases without mucking with changing desktop files was to do the following two commands:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/nautilus /usr/bin/nautilus.bak
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pcmanfm /usr/bin/nautilus
```

You can of course replace `/usr/bin/pcmanfm` with `/usr/bin/thunar`, or whatever.

**Edit**: If you also want to have a desktop, open `/etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop` and make the Exec line

```
Exec=nautilus --desktop
```

Comment: I could not find nautilus-autostart.desktop in that folder, any idea where I could find it?

Comment: You could run `locate nautilus-autostart.desktop` in the terminal, but it really should be there (at least in 12.04 LTS).

Comment: Thanks for that tip, Syzygy. For some reason, I could not see it by navigating to the folder (even when showing the hidden files), however this command located it where you said it was (in 12.10). I could then modify it with the command `sudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/nautilus-autostart.desktop`.

Comment: Glad it worked out, maybe I changed the permissions of the file at some point. Forever a mystery!

Comment: Of course, if you change the desktop handler, you need to change the way background images &c are set up, if you do that from scripts.

Comment: Also note that if you softlink /usr/bin/nautilus to PCManFM, this change will probably be overwritten if we get an update with a new nautilus binary.

If you only want to fix the current problem of Nautilus jumbling the desktop icons (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1063487) it's enough to edit the autostart file and change the Exec line to 

Exec=pcmanfm --desktop

Comment: I'd be cautious doing this in 14.04 -- after I setup pcmanfm to be the default I wasn't able to log in after the screen locked.

Answer (score 12):

I think the bottom method from the [community entry on Default File Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager) is very easy, and I just tested it for SpaceFM (feature-richer PcManFM fork).

In terminal, execute

```
 exo-preferred-applications
```

Then move to the `Utilities` tab, and under **File Manager**, choose your weapon of choice.

Comment: unfortunately its still the same, oh well, i will stick with nautilus then..its not that easy as i thought it will be:)

Comment: Apparently this needs `exo-utils` to be installed.

Comment: tried 'edit' methods mentioned everywhere.... but it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this. I prefer to do it manually (editing /usr/share/applications/defaults.list or for a per user approach  ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list) but you can use the graphical tool exo-preferred-applications. Anyway, you can find detailed instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager

Answer (score 1):

I did all the procedures reccomended here and I couldn't get pcmanfm to open all my files. Somehow, using google chrome's "open folder" for a new download always popped up a new nautilus window or worse, a new nemo window (since I'm using cinnamon).

What finally solved my problem was to type

```
gksudo nautilus /usr/share/applications
```

and finding every app that was supposed to launch a file manager. I had nemo, nautilus, file-roller, files, etc. Right clicking on them and then on properties, I saw some of them launched nemo, some others launched nautilus. I just replaced pcmanfm everywhere I saw fit. Now everything launches pcmanfm.

Answer (score 0):

The file you should edit is `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop` to something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=pcmanfm %U
Icon=system-file-manager
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.4.2
Actions=Window;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=pcmanfm
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Comment: Biblioclasta, didnt help, its still the same ;)

Answer (score -2):

uninstalling nautilus should do the trick

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus
```

Comment: yep, but now i cant handle the desktop...i dont see icons that used to be on it..there is a need for more steps.. any ideas?

Comment: oh and right click on desktop also dont work

Comment: so, no more ideas? :)

Comment: You can run PcManFm as your desktop manager by running `pcmanfm --desktop`. You can then add this to command to startup applications.