# Optimize Ubuntu 13.04 for netbook (Dell Mini 10v)

Tags: 13.04, performance, dell-mini-10

I have some slight glitches running Ubuntu 13.04 in my old beloved Dell Mini 10v. How can I optimize the graphics for it?

It has got 1Gb of RAM and an N270 Atom processor. Very minimal graphics too.

Comment: check the last update in my answer, may be it will help you ..http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install Unity Tweak Tool from the Ubuntu Software Center and change the launcher and the search configs.

Answer (score 2):

I run Ubuntu 13.04 on a netbook too and this is what I do to optimize the machine:

1. Install PCMan File Manager (or PCManFM) to replace Nautilus as the [default File Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211325/how-to-set-pcmanfm-as-the-default-file-manager).
2. Install [Synapse](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synapse/) to replace Unity's application laucher.
3. Remove unused apps and packages.
4. Optional: install Xfce 4 to replace Unity.

Comment: I always had pain with a non-unity desktop on Ubuntu

Comment: @sarat my experience is that you install Unity first to get the assets, and then install other desktop managers.

Answer (score 1):

OS use SWAP memory, which is located in HDD. HDD is slower than RAM, reducing the percentage of SWAP memory in HDD will increase the speed.

Check your percentage of  SWAP memory using this command:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Result will be 0 to 100. To change the swappiness type this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add or change the line with minimum value (0 to 10)

```
vm.swappiness=10
```

Restart your Notebook and enjoy :)

Comment: please explain why changing swappiness will help with graphics.