# How to make "File" (default file manager in Ubuntu 13.04) as default file manager?

Tags: 13.04, default, filemanager

Before I use Nautilus as my default file manager, I also have a file manager called File. I changed File with Nautilus, but I don't know how to change File as my default file manager again.

Can you guys help me out? Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default file Manager, you can follow the instructions posted on [How to set PcManFm as the default file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211325/how-to-set-pcmanfm-as-the-default-file-manager?rq=1)

All you need do is substitute pcman to file.

Hope this helps.